# Linux, bash. Detect is usb device data transfer is active

Tags: linux, bash, usb, stat

I want to detect the file/data transfer via USB is active on any plugged USB device.
Is it possible to detect the file/data transfer?

Comment: You can check new device using `lsblk `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [usbmon](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt) would work for your requirements.
It detects data packet transfers on the bus.

You would have to define a threshold for the transfer. I would recommend logging the values during different activities to use in a parsing script.

Since usbmon can get a little messy to implement you can use [usbtop](https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop) it's much better implemented.

You can find installation instructions on this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/usb-performance-traffic-monitor/489268#489268)